# catch the file when we "open with" file to a electron app

Tags: electron

*Catch the file when we "open with" file to a electron app*

I have created media player in electron and want any media file to play inside my app whenever i right-click and open with my-app, should play the video, which not happening now. Technically, i want to catch the file and play it, whenever its open-with my-app.

I have created media player in electron and want any media file to play inside my app whenever i right-click and open with my-app, should play the video, which not happening now. Technically, i want to catch the file and play it, whenever its open-with my-app.

I hope you guys will help me to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `open-file` event on the `app` object when running on macOS, on windows you need to parse `process.argv`. See the docs: https://electronjs.org/docs/all#event-open-file-macos